# Is there an alternative to args.EQUAL()?

Tags: java, args

I'm current learning Java and working through a text book.

I have this piece of code given by the book which works bit like a calculator:

```
int num1= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int num2= Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
String msg = args[0] + args[1] + args[2] + "=";

if (args[1].equals("+")) msg += (num1 + num2));
else if (args[1].equals("-")) msg += (num1 + num2));
```

and so on.

In console you would do something like: `java Args 10 + 2`

What I want to know is if something like this can work (I haven't managed to make it work yet)

```
if(args[1] == "-") msg += (num1-num2));
```

Comment: No don't compare String values using `==`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @ZouZou thanks I will read

Comment: It is not "args.EQUAL"; it is [`String.equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) ..

Comment: Note that in your example "java Args 10 + 2", `args[0]` is actually "Args".

Comment: @kviiri No, it's the name of the class. `args[0]` will be 10!

Comment: @ZouZou, haha, true! I got this mixed up with Python where the first argument is the name of the script being ran. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @ZouZou It is name of class (just to confirm). Should of mentioned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `equals()` method checks the actual contents of the string, the `==` operator checks whether the references to the objects are equal.  Note that string constants are usually "interned" (except the argument values as they are not compile-time constants) such that two constants with the same value can actually be compared with `==`, but it's better not to rely on that.

```
if (string1.equals(string2)) {
    ...
}
```

Taken from: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) , with some modifications.

Comment: Argument values are not interned because they are not compile-time constants.